# Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI is no more?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, browser-history

I am trying to add content observer for **AOSP Browser's** history provider i.e., with Uri **Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI**. If I attach an observer, the onChange(boolean) gets called on my **ICS** running my **Samsung GT-S7562**, my **JB** running **Samsung GT-I8262** or **HTC Desire X** but I don't get any notifications for AOSP Browser provider on my friend's **Android 4.3** running **Samsung SM-G7102**. However for **Google Chrome's** provider, i.e., residing at **content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks**, I get notified for changes on all android releases. Also if I query the **AOSP Browser** database & scan for entries, it only returns those opened in Chrome (I mean it returns **Chrome's** history in **Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI** provider).

Below is the sample service I tested for reference which is not actually required (don't mind but I think everything is quite clear above already):

```
package vpz.hp;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Watcher extends Service {
    private Provider Browser;
    private Provider Chrome;
    @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override public void onDestroy() {
        if (this.Browser != null)
            this.Browser.Stop();
        if (this.Chrome != null)
            this.Chrome.Stop();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    public final int onStartCommand(Intent Intention, int StartId, int Flags) {
        this.Browser = new Provider(super.getApplicationContext(), android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI);
        this.Browser.Start();
        if (Search(getApplicationContext(), "com.android.chrome")) {
            this.Chrome = new Provider(super.getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse("content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks"));
            this.Chrome.Start();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    private static final boolean Search(Context Sender, String Package) {
        try {
            return Sender.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(Package, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES) != null;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException Error) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    private static class Provider extends ContentObserver {
        private Context Sender;
        private Uri URI;
        public Provider(Context Sender, Uri URI) {
            super(new Handler());
            this.Sender = Sender;
            this.URI = URI;
        }
        @Override public void onChange(boolean Self) {
            String Message = this.URI.toString() + " onChange(" + Self + ")";
            Toast.makeText(this.Sender, Message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("VPZ", Message);
        }
        public final void Start() {
            this.Sender.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(this.URI, true, this);
        }
        public final void Stop() {
            this.Sender.getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(this);
        }
    }
}
```

I have added below permission(s) already in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
```

Is content observer on **AOSP Browser** has been deprecated?

Comment: I think **samsung** is using different provider/database for storing browser history instead of _standard_ android browser provider. As I saw, the browser app is in Samsung folder on 4.2.2+ devices (meaning Samsung specific). This gives an unclear idea of the fact that the browser in newer releases isn't one from **AOSP** source tree.